# Rails create does not save params from checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a website where a user (`interviewer`) can create a `position` (a job opening).

Even if the params are sent, my create action does not save them except for the `current_user`.

This is what I send: [image: My params when I select Javascript and ruby from the checkbox]

**positions_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @position = Position.new
  end

  def create
    @position = Position.new(position_params)
    @position.interviewer = current_interviewer
    if @position.save
      redirect_to position_path(@position)
      flash[:success] = "You created a new position/opening"

    else
      render :new
    end
    raise
  end
  private

  def set_position
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])
  end

  def position_params
    params.require(:position).permit(:title, :skills, :interviewer)
  end

end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= simple_form_for [@interviewer, @position] do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :title, required:true %>

    <%= f.input :skills, as: :check_boxes, collection:[
    ['Python', "python"],
    ['Java', "java"],
    ['JavaScript', "javascript"],
    ['Ruby', "ruby"],
    ['C++', "c++"],
    ['Node.js', "node"],
    ['React', "react"],
    ['Django', "django"],
    ['Rails', "rails"],
    ['SQL', "sql"],
    ['Doker', "doker"],
    ['AWS', "aws"],
    ['Vue.js', "vue"],
    ['Marketing', "Marketing"],
    ['HR', "hr"],
    ['Finance', "finance"],
    ['IT', "it"],
    ], input_html: { multiple: true } %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit position", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

**position.rb**

```
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true

  belongs_to :interviewer
end
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "positions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.bigint "interviewer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "candidate_id"
    t.string "candidatures", default: [], array: true
    t.string "skills"
    t.index ["candidate_id"], name: "index_positions_on_candidate_id"
    t.index ["interviewer_id"], name: "index_positions_on_interviewer_id"
  end
```

My alternative was to replace the create code with:

```
@position = current_interviewer.positions.new(position_params)
```

**but it still does not work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `input_html: { multiple: true }` for the params `skills`, you need to add the following in **positions_controller.rb**:

```
 def position_params
    params.require(:position).permit(:title, :interviewer, :candidate, skills:[])
  end
```

Basically, your `skills` will be saved as an array if you allow `input_html: { multiple: true }` for a collection

In addition, you are not passing any params for `candidate`

Answer (score 1):

In your table, you have `interviewer_id` but in your permitted params you have `interviewer`.

Change your params to permit `interviewer_id` instead.

Also, in your form you have `<%= f.input :title, required:true %>` Presence is required by default (at least with simple_form). You don't need to declare it in the form, but you should still keep it in your Model.